# Can a semialgebraic function be continuously extended to the closure of its domain?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $C$ be a bounded semialgebraic set and $F: C \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded and continuous semialgebraic function.

Is it true that $f$ can be continuously extended to the closure of $C$?  I was not able to find a counter-example, but I believe I am missing something and unable to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $C = [-1,1]\setminus \{0\}$, and define: $$F(x)= \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if }x>0\\ 0&\text{if }x<0.\end{cases}$$
$C$ and $F$ are bounded and semialgebraic, and $F$ is continuous on $C$, but $F$ cannot be continuously extended to $\overline{C} = [-1,1]$.

Comment: What if $C$ is connected?

Comment: @AlexShtof If $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $C$ is an interval), then you just have to extend $F$ to at most $2$ limit points, and there's no problem. In higher dimensions, it's still false. For example, take the circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin, remove the point $(1,0)$, and define $F(x,y) = x+1$ if $y>0$ and $F(x,y) = -(x+1)$ if $y\leq 0$.